# "is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger" When After Insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I want to create trigger when **Table1** insert value Quantity make value increase on Storage Column **Table 2**, but i have 'insert into' condition like this:

```
INSERT INTO buy_stock (name,id_product,quantity,total,date) VALUES ('Joe',(SELECT id_product FROM product WHERE name_product='Laptop'),3,410,NOW());
```

My Trigger to create add stock for product table:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `add_stock` AFTER INSERT ON `buy_stock` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  UPDATE product SET stock = stock + new.`quantity` WHERE id_product = new.id_product;
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The id_product in **Table 1** is FK from **Table 2** or product table, when i execute the insert into query i got this error

```
Can't update table 'product' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

Anyone got an idea to insert data but have condition like query above?

Comment: Use transactions instead of triggers and put the INSERT and UPDATE in the same transaction.

Comment: The published trigger is not directly causing the error - Do you have a trigger(s) on product?

Comment: @P.Salmon i just have that trigger on my whole db

Comment: @danblack i'll learn for that later, but i have no idea to used that on my java insert form

Comment: Correction the error is thrown by the select from product in the insert. Remove that and the code works as expected.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes indeed, but i need that condition to insert fk by combo box / input option select values